# Is it possible to clone/repack a sprite sheet with new images?

Tags: graphics, cocos2d-iphone, textures, sprite-sheet

Here is an example scenario

Project A has a 2048x2048 sprite sheet and when unpacked, has 50 png images spread over the sprite sheet.

Project B is needed to be a clone, however, it has 50 DIFFERENT png images recreated in exact same dimensions and file names however they are different images.

Can you make it so that the new images appear in EXACTLY the same place as in Project A? And the resulting sprite sheet is exactly the same dimensions, just different images?

Chris

Comment: try texture packer / zWoptex

Comment: texture packer can do this for you. And if you use spriteframenames the location of each image simply doesn't matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference, what size your spritesheet has. And what images contents. For your program it is just texture with description, that allows to create spriteframes with different parts of this texture and make them alias with spriteframe names. You can split your spritesheet(create two instead of one), change pictures, etc. The only thing that you can worry about is that all spriteframes should have the same names if you don't want to change the code of your project. Oh, and if you don't want to change positions, new spriteframes must have the same dimensions. As you mentioned, you've already followed these requirements, so you can feel free to use new spritesheet.